# XML parser for other browsers except IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, xml-parsing

How to write below piece of code so that it works on all browser. Currently it is workng in IE only.

```
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.loadXML(respText);

var element1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("element1");
var element2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("element2");
```

Appreciate any guidance in resolving this?

Thanks,
Jdp

Comment: the same thing (pretty much) is available as responseXML from any ajax request, so long as the url loaded is xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would jQuery I would first just retrieve the data through a normal `GET` request and then use [`jQuery.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to parse it. This takes care of all the different cross platform issues and additionally gives you some excellent tools to handle the xml structure more easily.

Of course there are other libraries as well who do similar things, but I would not advice you to do this from scratch yourself as there are quite a number of browser differences I can tell you from experience (I mean, you could just use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and you will get quite far, but there are some frustrating differences between older browser implementations).

And one last thing, never ever disable `async` loading of resources. Why risk irritating the user with freezing his browser if JS is build to make `async` processing easy in regards to some functions at least such as loading external resources.